# I keep on getting this error called "frame object is not callable"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a code where you put your name, and birthdate, and a dropdown asking for your gender and it will sort everything into listboxes. here is my code. the error is on line 118
"add = Button(fr, text="submit", command=lambda:[adi(), gen(), age()]).pack()" where it says that the frame object is not callable

```
from tkinter import*
from datetime import date
from tkinter import messagebox
one = Tk()
one.title("cideytfydy")
one.state("zoomed")
today = date.today()




clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Male")
def adi():
    a.insert(END, e.get())
def gen():
    if clicked.get() == "Male":
        b.insert(END, e.get())
    else:
        c.insert(END, e.get())
def age():
    d= int(birth_day.get())
    m=int(birth_month.get())
    y=int(birth_year.get())
    age = today.year-y-((today.month, today.day)<(m,d))
two = [
"Male",
"Female"
]

frame = Frame(one)
frame.pack(pady=5)

lf = Frame(frame)
lf.pack(pady=5)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Name")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

a = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
a.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Male")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

b = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Female")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

c = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
c.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH,padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Age")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

d = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
d.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

fr = Frame(one)
fr.pack(pady=20)


e = Entry(fr, font=("Futura", 30))
e.pack(pady=20)



age = Frame(fr)
age.pack(pady=10)

xo = Frame(age)
xo.pack()

Label(xo, text="Birth Year", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)
Label(xo, text="Birth Month", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)
Label(xo, text="Birth Date", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)

yearvalue = StringVar()
monthvalue = StringVar()
dayvalue = StringVar()

birthyear = Entry(age, textvariable=yearvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birthyear.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)
                 
birthmonth = Entry(age, textvariable=monthvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birthmonth.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

birthday = Entry(age, textvariable=dayvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birthday.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

drop = OptionMenu(fr, clicked, *two ).pack(pady=10)   
add = Button(fr, text="submit", command=lambda:[adi(), gen(), age()]).pack()




#LABEL/BUTTON

one.mainloop()
```

I keep on getting this error called Frame object is not callable in line 118

line 118 is this line. "add = Button(fr, text="submit", command=lambda:[adi(), gen(), age()]).pack()"

would someone be able to help me with this?

Comment: You are using `age` as the name of both a function and a Frame.  It cannot be both of those things at the same time...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. When there is a problem that you can't solve yourself, even after reducing the problem to the minimal related code and using your debugger, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. If there is something you don't understand, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look it up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+%22is+not+callable%22) first.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has various further issues you have still to fix. I have fixed only some of them, so that now the error message you mentioned went away:

```
from datetime import date
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk, StringVar, Frame, Label, LEFT, BOTH, Listbox, Entry, OptionMenu, Button, END
# from tkinter import *

one = Tk()
one.title("cideytfydy")
one.state("normal")
today = date.today()

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Male")
def adi():
    print("adi")
    a.insert(END, e.get())
    a.update()
def gen():
    print("gen")
    if clicked.get() == "Male":
        b.insert(END, e.get())
    else:
        c.insert(END, e.get())
def age():
    print("age")
    d   = int(birth_day.get())
    m   = int(birth_month.get())
    y   = int(birth_year.get())
    age = today.year-y-((today.month, today.day)<(m,d))

def subm():
    adi()
    gen()
    age()


two = [
"Male",
"Female"
]

frame = Frame(one)
frame.pack(pady=5)

lf = Frame(frame)
lf.pack(pady=5)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Name")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

a = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
a.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Male")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

b = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Female")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

c = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
c.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH,padx=10)

my_label = Label(lf, font=("Futura", 40),fg="#FFFFFF", text="Age")
my_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=120)

d = Listbox(frame,
font=("Futura", 25),
width=20,
height=6,
bd=2,
fg='#FFFFFF'
)
d.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=10)

fr = Frame(one)
fr.pack(pady=20)


e = Entry(fr, font=("Futura", 30))
e.pack(pady=20)

agf = Frame(fr)
agf.pack(pady=10)

xo = Frame(agf)
xo.pack()

Label(xo, text="Birth Year", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)
Label(xo, text="Birth Month", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)
Label(xo, text="Birth Date", font=("Futura", 30)).pack(pady=10, side=LEFT, padx=120)

yearvalue = StringVar()
monthvalue = StringVar()
dayvalue = StringVar()

birth_year = Entry(agf, textvariable=yearvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_year.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)
                 
birth_month = Entry(agf, textvariable=monthvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_month.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

birth_day = Entry(agf, textvariable=dayvalue, font=("Futura", 30))
birth_day.pack(pady=20, padx=20, side=LEFT)

drop = OptionMenu(fr, clicked, *two ).pack(pady=10)   
# add = Button(fr, text="submit", command=subm).pack() # lambda:[adi(), gen(), agf()]).pack()
add = Button(fr, text="submit", command=lambda:[adi(), gen(), age()]).pack()
#LABEL/BUTTON

one.mainloop()
```